# Error while downloading Image on server using PHP

Tags: php

[image]I have written following code in my Yii framework controller. This code is working fine on my localhost but not working on server.

Can somebody please tell me whats wrong with the code

Following is my code which I have written in controller

```
public function downloadFile($dir,$file,$extensions=[]){
    if(is_dir($dir)){
        $path = $dir.$file;
        if(is_file($path)){
            $fileinfo=pathinfo($path);
            $extension=$fileinfo["extension"];
            if(is_array($extensions)){
                foreach($extensions as $e){
                    if($e===$extension){
                        $size = filesize($path);
                        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                        header('Content-Length: '.$size);
                        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file);
                        header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                        readfile($path);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }else{
            echo"error";
        }
    }
}

public function actionDownload(){   
    if(Yii::$app->request->get('file')){        
        $this->downloadFile("media/offer/",Html::encode($_GET["file"]),["jpg","png"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please review my answer. It wasn't complaining your tags, it was about your functions. It's proper way to handle downloading files from your server in yii2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You tagged `yii2`, but it's not yii2, its pure php.

How about use framework to do this?

```
public function actionFile($filename)
{
   $storagePath = Yii::getAlias('@app/files');

   // check filename for allowed chars (do not allow ../ to avoid security issue: downloading arbitrary files)
   if (!preg_match('/^[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+$/i', $filename) || !is_file("$storagePath/$filename")) {
      throw new \yii\web\NotFoundHttpException('The file does not exists.');
   }
   return Yii::$app->response->sendFile("$storagePath/$filename", $filename);
}
```

[Yii2 - sendFile()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-response.html#sendFile()-detail)

^Change storagePath to your file directory.

And that's all, nothing more to do.

Answer (score -1):

Replace this function with yours,

```
public function downloadFile($dir,$file,$extensions=[]){
    if(is_dir($dir)){
        $path = $dir.$file;
        if(is_file($path)){
            $fileinfo=pathinfo($path);
            $extension=$fileinfo["extension"];
            if(is_array($extensions) && in_array($extension, $extensions)){

                header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
                header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
                header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($path));
                header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
                header('Expires: 0');
                header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
                header('Pragma: public');
                header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
                ob_clean();
                flush();
                readfile($path);
                exit;

            }
        }else{
            echo"error";
        }
    }
}
```

I just called this with following,

```
downloadFile("/var/www/html/", "test.php", ['php']);
```

and it worked for me.

Comment: can explain what error you are getting? Whether its going inside the condition or not?

Comment: I have attached screenshot in question please refer

Comment: It seems there is an error in your code and you have not enabled errors, set ini_set('display_errors', 1);error_reporting(E_ALL); on top of your page and check what is shows.